# Accessing tuple elements in opl

Tags: tuples, cplex

I'm trying to get access tuple elements as follows in my .mod file:

tuple indexType {

```
int first_index;
int second_index;
};
{indexType}stu_info = ...;
execute{
   writeln(stu_info.first_index)
}
```

in my .dat file i have the following:

```
stu_info from DBRead(db,"select S_ID,MSC from table1");
```

But when i run the program it prints **undefined**.
I want to know how to access tuple elements in ibm cplex.Please help.

Comment: Lets try to take the database connection out of the picture and just get the basics working. Does it work if you just put simple data in a dat file? There are plenty of examples provided with CPLEX/OPL

Comment: Thanks for your comment.But for my project i need to get data from database.

Comment: Are you new to this kind of thing? When something isn't working, its normal to try something simpler. It is not clear whether the problem comes from your database connection or your OPL syntax for accessing the data. Trying simple data without using a DB is a sensible first step which is easy. Does that work? Can you read *any* data from the database? The database connection side is much more complicated to deal with as there are many different database systems (SQL Server, Oracle, Access etc) and ways of accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `find()` method in order to get your `stu_info` instance.

so instead of: `writeln(stu_info.first_index)`.
you should try: `writeln(stu_info.find(some key).first_index)`

Note: in order to use this you need to have some fields in the tuple as key.
For example,

```
tuple indexType {
 key int first_index;
 int second_index;
};
```